# How can I prevent my function from appending more than one button to an element?

Tags: jquery, click, append, closest

I have a set of `li`s and what I want is once I click on a especific `li` to change his background color and attach a button in it.

```
 <ul>
 <li class=opt>hi</li>
  <li class=opt>hello</li>
   <li class=opt>how are you</li>
    <li class=opt>come on</li>
     <li class=opt>go out</li>
      <li class=opt>lets go</li>
 </ul>
```

This is the code I have so far, the problem is that it attaches several buttons in the same `li` after the click.

```
    $('.opt').click(function(){


        button_click_me ="<button>click me</button>";


       $('li', $(this).css('background-color', '#F5F8FA').append(button_click_me).closest('ul')).not(this).hide();



    });
```

Comment: So you want to check whether a button already exists? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried the code I posted. for some reason it attaches several buttons in the li. the button is already defined. it exists.

Comment: I don't see where you're checking the DOM for existing buttons.

Comment: is this not enough? `button_click_me ="<button>click me</button>";`

Comment: That's not the DOM. That's code.

Comment: `if ($('#elementId').length > 0) {// exists.}` you mean something like this? is it part of the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the clicked li has a button by `$(this).find("button").length`

You can do something like:

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul>li').click(function() {

    //Add color and append button if unable to find a button
    if( !$(this).find("button").length ) $(this).css('background-color', '#F5F8FA').append("<button>click me</button>");

    //Hide all li except the clicked li
    $('ul>li').not(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class=opt>hi</li>
  <li class=opt>hello</li>
  <li class=opt>how are you</li>
  <li class=opt>come on</li>
  <li class=opt>go out</li>
  <li class=opt>lets go</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check whether there's a button already. Rather than relying on DOM element checks, which can be fragile, maybe add a class you can check for on subsequent clicks:

```
 $('.opt').click(function() {
   button_click_me = "<button>click me</button>";

   $(this).not('.has-button')
     .css('background-color', '#F5F8FA')
     .append(button_click_me)
     .addClass('has-button')
     .siblings().hide();
 });
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xfLpescm/4/)**